# generating MD5 hash of a text with C#

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5

I understand that System.Security.Cryptography has a MD5 hashing method in [MD5.ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tessz10c.aspx). However, the method takes and returns bytes. I don't understand how to work with this method using String key and hashes.  I try to work around by doing this,

```
var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"text".ToCharArray()));
foreach(byte h in hash)
{
    Console.Write((char)h);
}
```

However the resulting output is gibberish string. For comparison, in [this website](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php), entering "text" will result in "1cb251ec0d568de6a929b520c4aed8d1"

Comment: oops overlooked that the hash is usually formatted with hex. Interested persons please see my answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing this code will give the same result as the website:

```
var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"text".ToCharArray()));
foreach(byte h in hash)
{
     Console.Write(h.ToString("x2"));
}
```

The trick is to print each byte as 2 hexadecimal digits (hence x2)